# How to transfer world saved on linux desktop to minecraft server on linux computer using linux commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, hosting

So i have been trying to transfer a minecraft world save from my linux desktop to my linux minecraft server but have no idea how to move from desktop directory to linux server directory. I am also using amazon aws to host my minecraft server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, **Shut down the server**. If you open the folder the server is in, there should be a folder called world. Get the world file that you want to use for your server, then drag that into the server folder. Then name the world you want to use world. So it replaces the unwanted world. Then relaunch the server.